# Trim on SSD on windows 7 with ide mode

Tags: windows-7, ssd, sata

I have an ssd on ide mode in windows 7. (its a clone of the hdd and that was in ide mode). I just turned on ahci mode (after using it 2 months in ide mode) and it works faster. I was wondering if there was trim enabled while it was in ide mode (windows 7 detected that it was a ssd - disk defrag was disabled). I heard multiple sources online say it does have trim because the something ide.sys driver has trim support but some also say it does not.

Also if trim wasn't enabled, would there be any sustaining damage to the drive or did it only affect performance?

Comment: You're not going to damage a modern SSD from normal use.

Comment: What about excessive wear?

Comment: Wear is dependent only on the number of writes, thanks to wear leveling.

Comment: will the lack of trim increase the number of writes?

Comment: Theoretically, lack of trim could (worst case, under totally unrealistic conditions) double the number of writes. But under realistic conditions, it means just a few more writes per cell over the life of the drive, which is completely negligible.